# AngularJS: ngIf in array of objects with different properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have some issue with ngIf directive. I tried a lot of ways to resolve it, but unfortunately failed.

I have an array of objects with different properties. Something like this:

```
    object = [
    {
        name: "1",
        isNumber: true,
    },
    {
        name: "2",
        isNumber: true,
    },
    {
        name: "3",
        isNumber: true,
    },
    {
        name: "4",
        isNumber: true,
    },
    {
        name: "5",
        isNumber: true,
    },
    {
        name: "#",
        isNumber: false,
    },
    {
        name: "*",
        isNumber: false,
    }
```

I need to use ngIf on the last object with true value of isNumber property. I don't know how much objects with isNumber on true will be in my array. It can be 7 or 82. Nobody knows. Also objects with isNumber on false won't be always in my array. Sometimes array will be have only objects with isNumber on true and no objects with isNumber on false.

How can i achieve this using ngIf?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I have something like this:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, *, #.

And I don't want to have "Down" button on last element with true value of isNumber property (7 in this case). Because if user moves it down, I'll have this:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, *, 7, #.

And it will be wrong logic.

So, I need to use ngIf, so that I could disable this button on that element. But sometimes I can have smth like this (without extra symbols):

1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

And in this situation I don't need "Down" button on last element too. Because it's impossible to move last element down.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking. Do you want the `ng-if` to check if `isNumber` is true OR if it's the last element? Can you give some more code as well as the expected output?

Comment: I want to check if isNumber is true AND at the same time it must the last element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to find if it's the last element AND if `isNumber` is set to true, you can use this:

`<span ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.isNumber && $last">`

`$last` is a special variable defined through `ngRepeat`, located [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Since `ngIf` accepts a boolean statement, you can use both the logical `&&` and `||` operators.

**Edit:** if you're not iterating over it with `ngRepeat` and you just want to select the last element, you can do something like this to select the last one, then use `ngIf` to display it if `isNumber` is set to true:

`<span ng-bind="list[list.length - 1]" ng-if="list.isNumber">`

**Edit 2:** Could you "peek" at the next element and see if the next `isNumber` is set to false? Like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="...">
   <span ng-if="!list[$index + 1].isNumber"></span>
</span>
```

Like `$last`, I'm using a special variable called `$index` to go to the next element in the `ngRepeat`.
(not sure if Angular automatically checks out-of-bounds errors, or if it'll throw an error)

Comment: Is OP `ng-repeat`-ing over the array?

Comment: Hmm. I guess I just assumed OP was iterating over the array.

Comment: ngIf here returns true if the last element of array will be with isNumber on true. But what will be if the last element have isNumber on false? 

I need to disable "Down" button on the last element with true value of isNumber property. So that this element couldn't be possible to move down. I have something like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, #, *. And I don't want the last element (5 in this case) have "Down" button, because i'll get smth like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, #, 5, * - it will be an error.

Comment: I posted an update ("Edit 2"). Could you check if the next element in the iteration isn't a number?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, but thank you for help.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could do this to select #5: http://jsfiddle.net/qfpyrcot/2/ -- it checks to see if the current element is a number AND the next element is not a number. In the example, it puts a '>' right next to #5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90654/discussion-between-turak-vladyslav-and-ralph-wiggum).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial question was a bit confusing, but thanks to the edits I think I understand what you need. By using `$index` in combination with `$last`, you can achieve what you want to do in a simple way:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.name}}
    <button ng-if="!$last && items[$index + 1].isNumber">Down</button>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

The condition to display the *Down* button is `!$last && items[$index + 1].isNumber`. Indeed, we must show the button if:

- the current item is not the last one: `!$last`
- the next one IS a number: `items[$index + 1].isNumber`

  Note that we can peek at the next element without error because we checked earlier that we are not on the last item.

See **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2txvkjLs/)**